# DOM pdf codeigniter: Class 'DOMPDF' not found error

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

I trying to add DOM PDF library to my codeigniter application

1.Download dompdf  and copy the `dompdf` folder to libraries folder.

2.Create  file named `Dompdf.php` in libraries folder

In my controller

```
public function pdf_test()
   {
       $this->load->library('Dompdf');
       $this->Dompdf->loadHtml('hello world');
       $this->pdf->render();
       $this->pdf->stream("welcome.pdf");
   }
```

**Dompdf.php**

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * CodeIgniter PDF Library
 *
 * Generate PDF's in your CodeIgniter applications.
 *
 * @package         CodeIgniter
 * @subpackage      Libraries
 * @category        Libraries
 * @author          Chris Harvey
 * @license         MIT License
 * @link            https://github.com/chrisnharvey/CodeIgniter-PDF-Generator-Library
 */
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/dompdf/autoload.inc.php');
class Pdf extends DOMPDF
{
    /**
     * Get an instance of CodeIgniter
     *
     * @access  protected
     * @return  void
     */
    protected function ci()
    {
        return get_instance();
    }
    /**
     * Load a CodeIgniter view into domPDF
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string  $view The view to load
     * @param   array   $data The view data
     * @return  void
     */
    public function load_view($view, $data = array())
    {
        $html = $this->ci()->load->view($view, $data, TRUE);
        $this->load_html($html);
    }
}
```

But i will this error.

> Message: Class 'DOMPDF' not found
>
> Filename: libraries/Dompdf.php
>
> Line Number: 16

[I am  using latest DOMPDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/releases/download/v0.7.0-beta3/dompdf_0-7-0_beta3.zip)

Answer (score 5):

in my case. i use this

> $dompdf = new Dompdf\DOMPDF();

```
require_once(_MAP."libraries/dompdf/autoload.inc.php");
$dompdf = new Dompdf\DOMPDF();
$html = 'rats :)';
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
```

Comment: For some reason I couldn't use `use Dompdf\Dompdf;` because it wouldn't load anything. By putting the namespace in the declaration it solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with v0.7.0 Dompdf uses namespaces. You probably need to add a `use` statement prior to referencing the class. Or reference it using the full namespace path.

Try:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/dompdf/autoload.inc.php');
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
class Pdf extends Dompdf
{
...
}
```

Usage is available in the [readme](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/v0.7.0-beta3/README.md) or on the [wiki usage page](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Usage).

Answer (score 2):

I simply changed

```
$dompdf = new Dompdf\DOMPDF();
```

to

```
$dompdf = new Dompdf\Dompdf();
```

inside the Pdf.php

Answer (score 0):

I have done pdf generation with `tcpdf` library but with a slightly different approach from you. Here is my solution with `tcpdf`. You can try it with `Dompdf`.

Download tcpdf and put in **third_party** folder
Make a file `PDF.php` in **libraries** folder with the following contents

```
 require_once APPPATH."third_party/tcpdf/tcpdf.php";

    class PDF extends TCPDF {
        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
        }
    }
```

In **controllers**  folder create a file `Createpdf.php` with following codes

```
defined("BASEPATH") OR exit("No direct script access allowed");

    class Createpdf extends CI_Controller {

        public function pdf()
        {
            $this->load->library("pdf");
            $data["content"] = "Hello from CodeIgniter with TCPDF...";
            $this->load->view("pdfreport", $data);
        }
    }
```

and the `pdfreport.php` view is:

```
$obj_pdf = new TCPDF('P', PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$obj_pdf->AddPage();
$obj_pdf->writeHTML($content, true, false, true, false, '');
$obj_pdf->Output('output.pdf', 'I');
```

Answer (score 0):

First install it by `composer`

```
composer require dompdf/dompdf
```

And use this in pdf library .

```
 require 'vendor/autoload.php';
 use Dompdf\Dompdf as Dompdf;
```